# custom hamcrest matcher succeeds but the test fails

Tags: junit, java-8, mockito, matcher, hamcrest

I have this custom matcher:

```
public class CofmanStringMatcher extends TypeSafeMatcher<String> {
    private List<String> options;


    private CofmanStringMatcher(final List<String> options) {
        this.options = Lists.newArrayList(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean matchesSafely(final String sentResult) {
        return options.stream().anyMatch(option -> option.equals(sentResult));
    }


    public static CofmanStringMatcher isCofmanStringOnOfTheStrings(List<String> options) {
        return new CofmanStringMatcher(options);
    }

    @Override
    public void describeTo(final Description description) {
        System.out.println("in describeTo");
//        description.appendText("expected to be equal to of the list: "+options);
    }
}
```

which compares a string to few options for strings.

when i run this test code:

```
    verify(cofmanService, times(1))
            .updateStgConfigAfterSimulation(argThat(isCofmanStringOnOfTheStrings(ImmutableList.of(expectedConditionsStrings , expectedConditionsStrings2))), eq(Constants.addCommitMsg+SOME_REQUEST_ID));
```

I get this error:

```
Comparison Failure:  <Click to see difference>

Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
cofmanService.updateStgConfigAfterSimulation(
    ,
    "add partner request id = 1234"
);
-> at com.waze.sdkService.services.pubsub.callback.RequestToCofmanSenderTest.localAndRtValidationSucceeds_deployCofmanStg(RequestToCofmanSenderTest.java:131)
Actual invocation has different arguments:
cofmanService.updateStgConfigAfterSimulation(
    "some text"
);
```

The test fails even though the method `updateStgConfigAfterSimulation` calls with 1st arg that matches on of the list elements

I'm using 
`mockito 1.10` and `hamcrest 1.3`

here is the method's signature

`void updateStgConfigAfterSimulation(String conditionsMap, String commitMsg) throws Exception`

Comment: Can you post your updateStgConfigAfterSimulation method?

Comment: your code can't be compiled, the `argThat` accept a `ArgumentMatcher` but you pass a `Matcher`. how did you get such an error?

Comment: At a quick glance you expect your `updateStgConfigAfterSimulation` to be called with 2 parameters - one for your matcher and one which is equal to `Constants.addCommitMsg+SOME_REQUEST_ID` - but your method is called using one parameter only - `some text`. As @Plog was suggesting, please you add the `updateStgConfigAfterSimulation ` implementation (maybe it takes a string vararg?!).

Comment: @holi-java no version is specified, but perhaps he's using mockito2 and importing [`MockitoHamcrest.argThat`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.47/org/mockito/hamcrest/MockitoHamcrest.html#argThat(org.hamcrest.Matcher)) which takes a hamcrest matcher as an argument

Comment: @holi-java     `public static <T> T argThat(Matcher<T> matcher)`

Comment: @Plog here is the method: `    void updateStgConfigAfterSimulation(String conditionsMap, String commitMsg) throws Exception;
`

Comment: @Morfic added my only `updateStgConfigAfterSimulation` signature

Comment: Where? All the changes I can see are the mockito and hamcrest versions...

Comment: @Morfic sorry it was in the comment. added to the post

Comment: So the method expects 2 arguments, but the invocation failure message describes just one which is weird, maybe a typo or copy-paste of a previous run?!. I created a local test based on your description and I can easily make it pass, so at this point I fell a [sscce](http://sscce.org) is required for closer inspection or debugging purposes.